# copy the values of one rows into remaining rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2.

```
DF1                            DF2
Column1 Column2                Column3  Column4 Column5 Column6
  A        B                     C        D        E       F
                                 G        H        I       J
                                 K        L        M       N
```

I'm getting the following results when I concatenate the two data frames:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
  A        B      C        D        E       F
                  G        H        I       J
                  K        L        M       N
```

However, I want the intended result to be as :-

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
  A        B      C        D        E       F
  A        B      G        H        I       J
  A        B      K        L        M       N
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) .

Assuming final concated DataFrame as `df`

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
```

Should Gives #

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
  A        B      C        D        E       F
  A        B      G        H        I       J
  A        B      K        L        M       N
```

If you want to do at once then

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Ohh..so I have to write the each column name? or is there any other way also?

Comment: Upadted @arvin.

Comment: Will the empty values in the df2 be filled as well?

Comment: Apply this after concatination

Comment: I tried it is also filling the empty values of df2..

Comment: Then apply second part of code on df1 and then concat

Comment: But rows of DF2 are not fixed